# When do stacks get inserted into people?

Tags: altered-carbon

People can obviously reproduce (Lizzy was pregnant), so when do kids get stacks inserted?  At birth?  Some time later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The intro hologram has this info.**

In the first episode, as Kovacs is waiting with the other resurrected, the hologram guide mentions that cortical stacks are implanted at an age of 1.

This appears to be borne out by the departures area of the facility, with one of the old-looking sleeves recognizing "mommy", and clearly being a young child in an old body.